# How to send a raw transaction directly without sanity checks

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, cryptonote, transaction-data

Would be possible to create a transaction without doing sanity checks? In GUI/CLI normally it would check if there are enough monero in the wallet or it has been unlocked. Is there a way to broadcast a transaction without this checks and its up to the peers/miners to double check that your transaction is valid or has enough monero in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into /sendrawtransaction API call. [Dev Guide](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc#sendrawtransaction)

Comment: Is there a createrawtransaction or similar? TIA!